# C++ Linked list using Classes (OOP)

Tags: c++, oop, data-structures, linked-list

This is my first post on StackOverflow, as I am genuinely stuck. 
My issue is that everytime I run the following code, at the first call for the function InsertNode(), the return temp node has the correct values for next node and data. However, when the function is called again, for some reasons the head gets reset to data NULL and next pointer recursively pointing to the same address. I'm having a hard time implementing this in OOP, I have done this using plain structs successfully. But with OOP I'm confused as how to declare the Node* Node::InsertNode(Node* head), method in main, as I get an error that InsertNode is undeclared. So as workaround I declared InsertNode outside of the Node class as an independent function. I have a feeling that is what may be causing the issue. would appreciate some help on what is going on or what I should change in my code. Thank you!

hashtable.cpp

```
#include "Hashtable.hpp"
using namespace std; 
Node::Node(){

    data = NULL;
   Node* nextP = NULL;
};

Node::~Node(){

}

Node* InsertNode(Node* head, int data){

    Node* temp = new Node();

    if(head->nextP == NULL){

        head->data = data;
        temp->nextP = head;
        head = temp;

    } else if(head->nextP!=NULL){

        temp->nextP = head;
        temp->data = data;
        head = temp;
    }

    return head;
};

void Node::printNode(Node* head){
    Node* temp = new Node();
    temp = head;
    while(temp->nextP != NULL){
        printf("%d\n", temp->data);
        temp = temp->nextP;
    }
}
```

Hashtable.hpp

```
#ifndef Hashtable_hpp
#define Hashtable_hpp

#include <stdio.h>

class Node
{
public:
    Node* nextP;
    Node();
    ~Node();

    void printNode(Node* head);
    int data = NULL;

    private:


};
Node* InsertNode(Node* head, int data);

#endif /* Hashtable_hpp */
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stdio.h"
#include <string>
#include "Hashtable.hpp"

using namespace std;
Node head;
//Node* head = new Node();


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
   head =  *InsertNode (&head, 10);
   // head = temp2;
   head =  *InsertNode (&head, 20);
   // head = temp2;
   head =  *InsertNode (&head, 30);
   // head = temp2;

     //InsertNode(head, 20);

  Node printNode(head);

    return 0;


}
```

Comment: Tons of compiler warnings. One of them may be telling you that's wrong.

Comment: Your bug appears to be rather obvious. This is an excellent opportunity for you to learn how to use a debugger, in order to step through your code one line at a time, while examining the values of all variables and objects, in order to figure it out yourself. And the next time you find yourself in this situation, you'll be able to figure it out all by yourself, without asking for help on stackoverflow.com. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer.

Comment: Thank you. I have break points set at every line currently and able to see values being correctly set on the first run. But on the second run head gets reset to Null again. I realize my logic may be wrong from function. But I am trying to understand if declaring the InserNode function outside of the class has anything to do with the head node getting reset. The void type method (PrintNode) doesnt throw errors when declared inside the class, but if I declare the InsertNode method the same way: Node* Node::InsertNode(Node* head, int data); I get an error that the it is undefined.

Comment: "I'm confused as how to declare the Node* Node::InsertNode(Node* head), method" The direct answer is "First declare the function inside the class, then implement it." The correct answer is "You don't want to. You want to define and implement a linked list class and put the insert function in the linked list class."

Answer (score 0):

So I finally figured out the issue. Since initially I was referencing the class function InsertNode() directly, I was trying avoid the error that I was other getting with the undeclared identifier. So as a work around I moved the function outside of the class declaration, which then caused more problems as you saw above post. Now I realized that when the function exists inside the Class, I have reference it by first de-referencing (my terminology is probably wrong) the function using the following: head->InsertNode(head, data); 
I was initially trying different iterations of InsertNode(&head, data) or Node* InsertNode(&head, data) ... etc. Basically trying to brute force my way through the compiler :).

I am attaching the code below, please let me know your comments on what I can improve.

Hashtable.cpp

```
#include "Hashtable.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Node::Node(){

    data = NULL;
    Node* nextP = NULL;
};

Node::~Node(){

}

Node* Node::InsertNode(Node* head, int data){
    Node* temp = new Node();
    if(head->nextP == NULL){
        head->data = data;
        temp->nextP = head;

    } else if(head->nextP!=NULL){
        temp->nextP = head;
        temp->data = data;
    }

    return temp;
};


void Node::printNode(Node* head){
    Node* temp = new Node();
    temp = head;
    while(temp->nextP != NULL){
        printf("%d\n", temp->data);
        temp = temp->nextP;
    }
}
```

Hashtable.hpp

```
#ifndef Hashtable_hpp
#define Hashtable_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node
{
    int data = NULL;
    Node* nextP;
public:

    Node();
    ~Node();
    Node* InsertNode(Node* head, int data);
    void printNode(Node* head);
        private:
};


#endif /* Hashtable_hpp */
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stdio.h"
#include <string>
#include "Hashtable.hpp"

using namespace std;
Node* head = new Node();

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    Node temp2;
    head =  head->InsertNode (head, 10);
    head =  head->InsertNode (head, 20);
    head =  head->InsertNode (head, 30);
    head =  head->InsertNode (head, 40);
    head =  head->InsertNode (head, 50);
    head =  head->InsertNode (head, 60);
    head =  head->InsertNode (head, 70);
     head->printNode(head);

    return 0;
```